# Use awk to return value to the terminal from JSON

Tags: awk

Consider this JSON template, for an EC2 instance.

I want to get the value for the KeyName using `awk`.

I understand there is a way to do it with `jq`, it is shown in [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3825/how-to-find-out-the-used-key-pair-name-via-aws-cli)

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                    "ImageId": "someImageId",
                    "InstanceId": "someInstanceId",
                    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                    "KeyName": "someKeyName",
                    "LaunchTime": "SomeDate",
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "disabled"
                    },
                    "Placement": {
                        "AvailabilityZone": "someAvailabilityZone",
                        "GroupName": "",
                        "Tenancy": "default"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected value: someKeyName

Comment: That's not adequate sample input to test a potential solution against since it just contains 1 sunny day case. It's always much easier to find the text you want than it is to NOT find similar text you don't want. See my answer for details and a better sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robustly:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^[[:space:]]*"KeyName"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*/,"") {
    sub(/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*$/,""); gsub(/^"|"$/,""); print
}' file
someKeyName
```

The above protects against many variations of where `KeyName` could appear in your input, where white space could occur, which characters could be part of the quoted value, and whether there are quotes in the value or now. For example try any of the other solutions you have so far against this input which just has a couple of the possible variations of your input:

```
$ cat file
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                    "InstanceId": "someInstanceId",
                    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",

                    "FooKeyNameBar": 0,
                    "ImageId": "someKeyNameImageId",
                    "KeyName": "some,KeyName",

                    "LaunchTime": "SomeDate",
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "disabled"
                    },
                    "Placement": {
                        "AvailabilityZone": "someAvailabilityZone",
                        "GroupName": "",
                        "Tenancy": "default"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks Ed, very useful. I've voted for David's solution as it is the simplest. Your solution is very useful, so I voted up.

Comment: Picking the "simplest" solution isn't always the best idea as "simple" often  also means "fragile". I'm guessing you didn't try the other solutions using the alternative input I provided in my answer. My answer is less simple than the rest because it's more robust than the rest and as such will continue to work when you have different input than just the one sunny-day example you provided in your question.

Comment: it's a good advice. and it did change my mind. you are right. a robust solution is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

While `jq` is the proper tool, you can do it relatively easily in `awk` with:

```
awk '/KeyName/ {sub(/,/,"",$2); print $2}' file
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '/KeyName/ {sub(/,/,"",$2); print $2}' file
"someKeyName"
```

If you want to remove the `"` as well, you can use:

```
awk '/KeyName/ {sub(/,/,"",$2); gsub(/"/,"",$2); print $2}' file
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '/KeyName/ {sub(/,/,"",$2); gsub(/"/,"",$2); print $2}' file
someKeyName
```

Just to round out your `awk` choices, you can also use `match()` and `substr()` as follows to obtain the output without quotes:

```
awk '/KeyName/ {match($2,/[^"]+/); print substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '/KeyName/ {match($2,/[^"]+/); print substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
someKeyName
```

The functions `sub()`, `gsub()`, `match()` and `substr()` are explained at [GNU Awk User's Guide - String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short alternative

```
awk -v FS="\"" '/KeyName/{print $4}' input_file
```

**Explanation** By setting the field separator to '"' (`-v FS="\""`) we can print the value from the fourth field (`print $4`) on the line matching the regular expression "KeyName" (`/KeyName/`).